# Django rest spectacular - Customizing get_queryset()

Tags: python, django, drf-spectacular

I am trying to customize the redoc documents using DRF-Spectacular.

For some reason, the extend_schema class is not updating the description, summary or tags on the document. How can I customize this?

```
@extend_schema(
        summary="Get All Classes",
        description='This endpoint will return all the classes created by your account.',
        tags=["Class"]
    )

def get_queryset(self):                                            
    return super().get_queryset().filter(taxonomy__is_public=True) | super().get_queryset().filter(taxonomy__client=Client.objects.get(user=self.request.user))
```

Comment: I can't speak to `drf-spectacular` but this doesn't smell right- you wouldn't document `get_queryset()` as it isn't an API endpoint..it's just a method. The GET endpoint (and others) calls `get_queryset()` to provide the objects to the APIView (Or viewset)

Comment: @You were right. I just added :

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

while keeping get_queryset as it is and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to the comment. Yes annotating `get_queryset` has no meaning because it makes little sense. But you don't need to do

```py
@extend_schema(...)
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

just for the sake of annotation. Spectacular got another decorator for that:

```py
@extend_schema_view(
    get=extend_schema(description='get desc', responses=...),
    post=extend_schema(description='post desc', request=..., responses=...),
)
class YourView(APIView):
   ...
```

https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#drf_spectacular.utils.extend_schema_view